# Vscode Path Intellisense not working with jsconfig.json (next js)

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, autocomplete, next.js

My project structure is like this:

```
jsconfig.json
next.config.json
components
   |_atoms
       |_Button.jsx
       |_Button.module.scss
       |_...
   |_...
...
```

and inside the `jsconfig.json`, I have this:

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
      "baseUrl": ".",
      "paths": {
         "@/components/*": ["components/*"]
      }
   },

   "include": ["components/**/*", "api/**/*", "data/**/*", "pages/**/*", "utils/**/*"]
}
```

Next.js correctly imports the components and it's working, but on the developing side, autocomplete isn't working anymore!

for example, all of these import statements are working like a charm, but I manually wrote the path and autocomplete didn't help:

```js
import Button from "components/atoms/Button";    //works
import Button from "@/components/atoms/Button";  //works
import Button from "../components/atoms/Button"; //works if the relative path is correct
import styles from "./Button.module.scss";       //works inside Button.jsx
```

So there's no problem with next js, but [Path Intellisense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=christian-kohler.path-intellisense) isn't suggesting filenames anymore.
I renamed `jsconfig.json` to something else (to disable it) and this time, Path Intellisense works correctly, but next js can't import components.

How can I benefit from both? I want to have absolute imports and also use Path Intellisense.

Comment: same here, were you able to find a solution?

Comment: I switched to Path Autocomplete Extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ionutvmi.path-autocomplete

Comment: By the way, I was facing the exact same issue with you and after trying everything, I discovered that there was something wrong with my VsCode configs/settings. Factory reset the vscode solved the problem. https://www.shellhacks.com/reset-visual-studio-code/

Answer (score 0):

If you just created a new `jsconfig.json` (or `tsconfig.json`) file, or made changes to it, you'll need to do the following to get it to work properly:

Restart server (for nextjs). Restart VSCode (for autocomplete).

That is,

- Stop server
- Restart VSCode
- Start server

Comment: I've done this probably a thousand times :-)